# delete record from db via table

Tags: php, mysql, database

i showing my users from database in html table i am make a button for every record in table for delete the record but i do not know how to do that
this is my code:

```
<table width="200" border="1">

    <?php
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        ?><tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">user</th>
            <th scope="row">pass</th>
            <th scope="col">edit</th>

        </tr>


        <td><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['user']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['pass']?></td>
        <td><a href="delone.php"><button>edit</button></a></td>
        </tr>

        <?php
    }
    ?>


</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are providing 'edit' option for every users. if u want to add delete option, that is : 'id, user, pass' of the user will be deleted. 
To do that just add this below edit option.

`<td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" >Delete </a></td>`

Now, using sql query you can delete that information from your db.

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

      // write query to delete from db
}
```

Now record will be deleted from your Database. Do it carefully!
Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

First,You have passed $_row in delete query. $_GET['id'] should be passed in palace  of $_row.

Second,mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); This statement has no purpose for deletion

Third, use prepare statements to avoid  mysql injections and validate $_GET['id'] value

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$myConnection= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect to mysql"); 

mysqli_select_db($myConnection, "test") or die ("no database");
 
 //query
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

      // write query to delete from db
 $sql="DELETE FROM `userpass` WHERE id='$_row'";
}
$result=mysqli_query($myConnection,$sql);
mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
</body>
</html>
```